# Troubleshooting Spring Boot app that won't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, spring-boot

I built the MySQL connector and the database details into the app and it still wont connect to MySQL when running in Tomcat. My app is entirely open source and all source code is on the web at: https://github.com/clickcell/AutomationStatisticsPortal

[The application.class](https://github.com/clickcell/AutomationStatisticsPortal/blob/9abd751fa7fee73e6df68c4926b03c773284f726/src/main/java/portal/Application.java)

[The gradle build file](https://github.com/clickcell/AutomationStatisticsPortal/blob/master/build.gradle)

The application.properties file, different from my repository, is:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/springboot
spring.datasource.username=newuser
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

I have tried setting up the MySQL 5.5 server to match application.properties

Every time the symptom is as follows:

Web app running but there is no database connection, no data being displayed.

I use Tomcat8 and MySQL 5.5. I have enabled the query log and monitor it using `tail -f` when I run queries direct to the server they show up in the log but when I reboot my app in the tomcat manager, nothing shows up in that log.

In the tomcat log I get the following:

```
21-Dec-2016 10:19:16.693 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/AutomationStatisticsPortal] has started
21-Dec-2016 10:19:17.339 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesJdbc The web application [AutomationStatisticsPortal] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
21-Dec-2016 10:19:19.026 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Dec-2016 10:19:26.839 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload Reloading Context with name [/AutomationStatisticsPortal] is completed
```

It looks like it's registering the wrong kind of database driver, but I do not know why given my configuration.

Comment: Do you get some errors? Exception and stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: There is no stack trace, I looked in `tomcat8-stderr.*` but I did find some useful messages, in my edit.

Comment: What do you mean "no data is displayed." Where is no data displayed?

Comment: Thanks @ChristopherSchultz , I have [this bootstrap class](https://github.com/clickcell/AutomationStatisticsPortal/blob/master/src/main/java/portal/bootstrap/TestCaseLoader.java) to load the initial data into the database, then it should show in the browser when I load the page. It doesn't make it as far as getting into the database, so my website just shows blank pages with the styling and no data. This is working in development with the H2 database, so I know what the page will look like when it's working in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log you've shown is produced when H2 is used.

I cloned your repository and tested locally, it works when I update the `src/main/resources/application.properties` with MySQL parameters.
You should remove the other one in root, it's ambiguous.

You could also replace your `application.properties` file in `src/main/resources` with this `application.yml` file:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost/springboot
        username: newuser
        password: password
    jpa:
      database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      database: MYSQL
      show-sql: true
```

In this case, add the Hikary dependency, or use another datasource type.

Comment: Thanks, I tried making your changes but the app does not start in tomcat, I get the error `At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs.`

Comment: This is an INFO, you can ignore it. If you want to use the Hikary version, make sure you include the dependency: mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP/2.5.1. But you can stick with the default. If you give write access to pblanchardie, I can push application.properties on GitHub.

Comment: I added the dependency, now I can confirm that queries are reaching the MySQL server, but I see that they get rolled back, and my app fails to start. I keep getting this error:

`SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive AutomationStatisticsPortal.war
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AutomationStatisticsPortal]]`

Comment: @clickcell You need to look at the other log files to find out why your application is failing to launch. That doesn't go into `catalina.out`.

Comment: The bottom of the stack trace in the manager log has `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'springboot.record_type' doesn't exist`

Comment: MySQL query log shows no CREATE statements are sent to the server, instead the statements look like:

`56 Query     SET NAMES latin1
                   56 Query     SET character_set_results = NULL
                   56 Query     SET autocommit=1
                   56 Query     SET autocommit=1
161222 14:52:30    47 Query     SET autocommit=0
                   47 Query     select count(*) as col_0_0_ from record_type recordtype0_
                   47 Query     rollback
                   47 Query     SET autocommit=1`

Comment: It doesn't find your record_type table, it means you have to create the schema manually or switch hbm2ddl mode to "create" or "update" or use liquibase to create it for you.

Comment: What is the difference between `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` ?

Comment: @PatriceBlanchardie I tried the property you suggested and it fixed my issue, thank you. My app now works properly with MySQL. My next challenge is to move the database credentials outside of the war file.

Comment: nice! both properties refer to the same feature. The first is the Hibernate name, used in Hibernate configuration, whereas the second is the Spring name, used in Spring configuration, which controls the first for you :) To move credentials out of the war, you have multiple options: use a datasource in tomcat with a jndi name, or externalise the properties with Spring to stay with your application's datasource. Have fun!